# How can I ensure my autocompleted spaces are fed into my function properly?

Tags: autocomplete, scripting, sh, zsh

I'm using [zsh](http://www.zsh.org/), and am trying to write a function to operate on a URL and a pathname:

```
function my-function
{
  somecommand --url $1 $(readlink -f $2)
}
```

(to complicate things somewhat, the function actually uses `sh` syntax, as it is sourced from my ~/.zshrc using [a trick like this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3449/18985)). The `readlink` is there to expand symlinks and ensure directories such as `.` are evaluated correctly (the directory name is stored for later use by `somecommand`).

When I type a command from the command-line like this:

```
my-function http://example.org/example /tmp/myexampledirectory
```

... it works fine, even if I autocomplete the directory name. However, if the directory name contains spaces, `zsh` completes it like this:

```
my-function http://example.org/example /tmp/My\ Example\ Directory
```

For most "normal" commands (cp, mv, etc.) that never seems to cause a problem. However, in my case, somecommand sees `$2` as only being `/tmp/My` - presumably the rest is seen as another argument.

How can I avoid this situation? I would prefer *not* to alter the standard `zsh` autocompletion, but rather find a way for my function to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The zsh completion system works very well here, and the solution is very simple, just put double-quotes around the `readlink` argument in the script:

```
somecommand --url $1 $(readlink -f "$2")
```

The point is that without quotes `readlink` removes backslashes which escape whitespaces. Compare three results:

**1.** Without backslashes and quotes `readlink -f` assumes that there are three different files/directories (with default path in current directory) and produces

```
$ readlink -f /tmp/My Example Directory
/tmp/My
/home/jimmij/Example
/home/jimmij/Directory
```

**2.** With escaping backslashes but without quotes `readlink -f` understands that there is only one directory, but removes backslashes from output, so that `somecommand` takes three separate arguments

```
$ readlink -f /tmp/My\ Example\ Directory
/tmp/My Example Directory
```

**3.** With backslashes and with double-quotes `readlink -f` gives the output with backslashes what is (most probably) expected by `somecommand`

```
$ readlink -f "/tmp/My\ Example\ Directory"
/tmp/My\ Example\ Directory
```

BTW, as a rule of thumb: if there are any problems with whitespaces in the shell-like scripts (bash, zsh, whatever) the first thing to play with is different quotation marks around variables.

Comment: `$2` doesn't need to be quoted, since parameter expansions (by default) don't undergo word splitting in `zsh`. Command substitutions, however, do. `somecommand --url $1 "$(readlink -f $2)"` (Of course, it won't *hurt* to quote `$2` as well.)

Comment: By the way, "playing with quotation marks" is a poor substitute for understanding what needs to be quoted and why.

Comment: (3) actually doesn't work. If I do (from bash) `readlink -f "/tmp/my\ dir/with\ spaces/"`, I simply get a return code of 1. Putting spaces around the whole readlink expression, though, as @chepner suggests, does work.